# Spring AOP - pointcut for every method with an annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I am trying to define a pointcut, that would catch every method that is annotated with (i.e.) `@CatchThis`. This is my own annotation.

Moreover, I'd like to have access to the first argument of the method, which will be of `Long` type. There may be other arguments too, but I don't care about them.

---

EDIT

This is what I have right now. What I don't know is how to pass the first parameter of the method annotated with `@CatchThis`.

```
@Aspect 
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(catchThis)")
    public Object logAction(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CatchThis catchThis) throws Throwable {
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect{

    @Pointcut(value="execution(public * *(..))")
    public void anyPublicMethod() {
    }

    @Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(catchThis) && args(.., Long ,..)")
    public Object logAction(
        ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CatchThis catchThis, Long long)
        throws Throwable {

        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post. Could you do the same with your snippet? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Thanks. is it possible, to catch methods which have ONE Long argument that is not necessarily the first argument - it can be first, second.. or last?

Comment: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'piano' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut`

This is what I get trying to use your aspect.. I am lost. + I removed the first .., from the args(..) - the error was different then.

Comment: I tried the answer, which I was looking for the whole afternoon, and it worked, in a very simple way. I was surprised how strong the aspecj and spring could be, as well as my Intellij IDEA knew the pointcut was valid by static code analysis.  Unfortunately, I could find the answer for this specific question on spring official doc.

Comment: Will this pointcut expression also cover object which are not spring managed? Meaning if I use @CatchThis annotation on a simple POJO, will the pointcut expression evaluate it?