# How could convert/implement spring aop function by annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I want to log time spent to log file when invoke some service methods , now I implement it by `AOP`, e.g.

```
@Around("execution(* sample..TaskService.*(..))")
public Object aroundStat(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    log.info("{} taken time: {} ms",methodName,(end-start));
    return proceed;
}
```

but I want to know how could implement it by using Annotation just like `@Trasactional`, e.g.

```
@Service
@TimeLogging
public class TaskService {
    @TimeLogging
    List<TaskStatDTO> taskStatusStat(String name){
        //...
    }

    List<TaskStatDTO> finishedTaskStat(String name){
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Could I implement some class and override some method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring AOP - pointcut for every method with an annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817822/spring-aop-pointcut-for-every-method-with-an-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

1. don't use system time for measure time execution , use StopWatch from spring or apache. see [good example - Measure execution time in Java – Spring StopWatch Example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/measure-execution-time-in-java-spring.html) and  [spring api StopWatch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html)

> ```
> long start = System.currentTimeMillis();    
> long end = System.currentTimeMillis();    
> (end-start)
> ```

change to

```
StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
watch.start();
..... execution
watch.stop();
watch.getTotalTimeMillis()
```

2. instead of

> @Around("execution(* sample..TaskService.*(..))")

use

> @Around("execution(* sample..TaskService.*(..) && @annotation(* sample...TimeLogging)")

see [Advice parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-schema-params)

better : see [Combining pointcut expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining) and [Sharing common pointcut definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-common-pointcuts)

```
@Pointcut("execution(@annotation(* sample...TimeLogging)")
private void withTimeExecutionLayer() {}

@Pointcut("execution(public *sample..service.* *(..))")
privatr void inServiceLayer() {}

@Pointcut("inServiceLayer() && withTimeExecutionLayer()")
private void auditTimeExecutionServiceLayer() {}
```

Comment: Thanks! but actually I want to know how to custom annotations just like `@Transactional`. If use spring aop it only could use at method level, if I want it , e.g. @TimeLogging on a class it does not support.

Comment: so in this case if I should use `@within ` to implement it